Are the 'pages' or 'app' directories in projects generally considered proprietary in Node
For example if someone has a GitHub repo that doesn't contain a pages or app directory, when you try to run npx next dev, you will get the following error.

  ▲ Next.js 14.2.3
  - Local:        http://localhost:3000

 ✓ Starting...
Error: > Couldn't find any `pages` or `app` directory. Please create one under the project root
    at findPagesDir (/Users/mattchen/node_modules/next/dist/lib/find-pages-dir.js:42:15)
    at initialize (/Users/mattchen/node_modules/next/dist/server/lib/router-server.js:75:69)
    at async Server.<anonymous> (/Users/mattchen/node_modules/next/dist/server/lib/start-server.js:249:36)

Is this pages or app directory generally considered proprietary? Like if I asked the GitHub repo owner what they used in those directories and if they would be willing to share them with me, would they generally say no?

Why would you run npx next dev in such a GitHub repo? Does that repo even use next.js?

Yes, it does use next.js.
